# Gap in elements in a row

Tags: html, css

On my page I have lots of elements, which i need to show by several in a row in straight columns. Each element is an image of equal size. When you click in it, on it's place appears a menu with tree on a row icons. All elements should be centered horizontally and vertically. There could be a different number of big images (6, 7, 8 or more) and from 1 to 9 elements in icon menu. Block with icons should be the same size as block with image. Image is 300px in max width and height and icons are 100px in max width and height. Each element (icons or image) block should has 350px in max width and height with 3.5% padding.   Now, I think I'm doing everything right, but elements logic on the page steel appears to be broken.

[My codepen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RrPbJG?editors=110)

```
<div class="item">
          <div class="logo">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/HyOMQFC.png">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <div class="links">
            <a href="#"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/wK9D1Ji.png"></a>
            <a href="#"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/wK9D1Ji.png"></a>
            <a href="#"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/wK9D1Ji.png"></a>
            <a href="#"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/wK9D1Ji.png"></a>
            <a href="#"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/wK9D1Ji.png"></a>
            <a href="#"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/wK9D1Ji.png"></a>
            <a href="#"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/wK9D1Ji.png"></a>
            <a href="#"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/wK9D1Ji.png"></a>
            <a href="#"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/wK9D1Ji.png"></a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <div class="logo">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/HyOMQFC.png">
          </div>
        </div>
```

css

```
.item {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 350px;
  max-height: 350px;
}

.logo,
.links {
  padding: 3.5% 3.5%;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 300px;
  max-height: 300px;
  display: inline;
  margin: 3.5%;
}

.logo img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 300px;
    display: inline;
}

.links img {
  width: 33%;
  max-width: 100px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
    display: inline;
}
```

What I get
[image]

What I need
[image: all cenetered up]

Comment: Your codepen is broken

Comment: Is it? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RrPbJG It works fine from private mode in chrome

Comment: you have specified width of the image to be 100%, so if the image is big then it will mess things up.. I think.. and your max is 300px..

Comment: http://s4.postimg.org/7ximdga8d/Untitled.png

Comment: and your max image size for the link images is 100.. So....

Comment: I _think_ the issue is that you are using "inline" for the display of the links.  Inline items don't have the same size controls that block items do.   Try with inline-block and see what happens.

Comment: @whatever is it working now? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RrPbJG

Comment: change the `display:inline-block` and put `vertical-align:middle` on the `items`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to place the `vertical-align:middle` on `items`.

you also need to change the size because the target is bigger than the rest by changing the inline to inline-block to resize the items.

Comment: why is there a shift in icons that way? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RrPbJG?editors=110

Comment: I mean this shift https://www.dropbox.com/s/jhi8mo5axxbl1as/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%88%D0%BE%D1%82%202015-12-11%2013.12.05.png?dl=0

Comment: shift?? did not understand